# temporarily suspend/disable FileVault

Tags: osx, disk-encryption

Is there a way, or does anyone know of a way to temporarily disable or suspend [File Vault](http://macadmins.psu.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/24696/2014/07/PSUMacAdmin2014_fv2_talk.pdf) disk encryption?
I know [fdesetup disable](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/fdesetup/) will decrypt the entire disk (which i don't want), but is there a way to suspend FileVault until next reboot for example?

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Either the disk is encrypted or it isn't. How would you use the encrypted disk if FV were turned off (and you didn't decrypt the disk)?

Comment: It is possible to "suspend" encryption with other FDE (Full Disk Encryption) software without decrypting the whole drive. For example BitLocker allows the suspension of encryption for a certain amount of reboots, I was wondering if the same is possible with FileVault.

Answer (score 0):

OK, unplugging power form the mac stops/halts the encryption process.